# Getting Whitepage error, cant find my issue in REST API?

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot

I am building a REST API to access a database and having trouble / consistently getting a whitepage error. Running in circles trying to find my error and/or my error in the flow or logic of the program.

Here is my application:

```
package com.skilldistillery.myRest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.skilldistillery.edgemarketing"})
@EntityScan("com.skilldistillery.edgemarketing")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.skilldistillery.myRest.repositories")
public class MyRestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyRestApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyRestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My controller:

```
package com.skilldistillery.myRest.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.skilldistillery.edgemarketing.entities.House;
import com.skilldistillery.myRest.services.HouseService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api") 
@CrossOrigin({ "*", "http://localhost:4200" })
public class HouseController {

    @Autowired 
    HouseService houseServ; 

    @GetMapping("index/{id}")
    public House show(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        return houseServ.show(id); 
    }

}
```

My repo:

```
package com.skilldistillery.myRest.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.skilldistillery.edgemarketing.entities.House;

@Repository
public interface HouseRepo extends JpaRepository<House, Integer>  {


}
```

My service:

```
package com.skilldistillery.myRest.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.skilldistillery.edgemarketing.entities.House;

@Service
public interface HouseService {

    List<House> index(); 

    House show(Integer id); 
}
```

And my ServiceImpl:

```
package com.skilldistillery.myRest.services;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.skilldistillery.edgemarketing.entities.House;
import com.skilldistillery.myRest.repositories.HouseRepo;

@Service
public class HouseServiceImpl {
    @Autowired
    HouseRepo hRepo; 

    public House show(Integer id) {
        Optional<House> opt = hRepo.findById(id); 
        House house = null;
        if (opt.isPresent()) {
            house = opt.get();
        }
        return house;
    }

}
```

It compiles and launches but via postman and browser, I am getting whitepage errors. I've scoured the internets trying to understand where I'm going wrong but not finding it. Please advise.

Comment: can you share the HTTP request from postman/browser? I also see you added CrossOrigin annotation, what is the purpose of that?

Comment: Thank you @ Adi-Ohana. 

Here's what postman is giving me in response to this request: 
http://localhost:8084/api/index/245034

{"timestamp":"2019-04-01T17:22:39.178+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/api/index/245034"}

I believe(d) the reason for the cross origin was to defeat the Cross Origin error. The example I was previously taught used it; I am open to criticism / learning.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with CrossOrigin.It only mean that your resource can be consumed by any client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution.
 Change your main class to the following code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyrestapplicationApplication  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyrestapplicationApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Then create a separate class for your configurations.As well as running away from tight coupled architecture.

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan("com.skilldistillery.edgemarketing.entities")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.skilldistillery.myRest.repositories")
public class BusinessConfig {

    @Bean
    public HouseService houseService(final HouseRepo houseRepo){
        return new HouseServiceImpl(houseRepo);
    }   
}
```

Your controller will then change to the following.Utilising Dependency Injection

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api") 
@CrossOrigin({ "*", "http://localhost:4200" })
public class HouseController {

   private   HouseService houseServ;

    public HouseController(HouseService houseServ) {
        this.houseServ = houseServ;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "index/{id}",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public House show(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        return houseServ.show(id); 
    }
}
```

HouseServiceImpl should also implement HouseService

```
public class HouseServiceImpl implements HouseService{
  private  HouseRepo hRepo;

    public HouseServiceImpl(HouseRepo hRepo) {
        this.hRepo = hRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public List<House> index() {
        return null;
    }

    public House show(Integer id) {
        Optional<House> opt = hRepo.findById(id); 
        House house = new House();
        if (opt.isPresent()) {
            house = opt.get();
        }
        return house;
    }

}
```

***NB**  - don't forget to remove the following configs `@Autowired,@Repository` as they are now handled within the `BusinessConfig` class.More Beans can be defined in the `BusinessConfig` Class

Comment: Thank you! This did it. I appreciate your help, very much. I'm going to analyze WHY this worked and compare it against the work I'd done. Again, thank you.